# addChildViewController not working when landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm using a container view controller to add a subview to my current view controller after 3 seconds:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self performSelector:@selector(open) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
-(void)open{
    ViewController2 *test = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    test.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self addChildViewController:test];
    [self.view addSubview:test.view];
}
```

ViewController2 is a simple view with just this on the init:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Here is the thing, if I open in portrait the second view and I rotate to landscape, the red color fills the screen, but if I open the second view from landscape, this happens:

[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to set the frame. The view interface when is open takes the size of the view you projected.

```
-(void)open{
    ViewController2 *test = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    test.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    test.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:test];
    [self.view addSubview:test.view];
}
```

As a suggestion: start to learn autolayout!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you.

```js
-(void)open{
    test = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    test.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    test.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:test];
    [self.view addSubview:test.view];
 }
```